# Loss of attributes with lapply (R)

Tags: r, attributes, lapply

If I have a list with some attribute, and I apply a function to all elements of that list, the attribute gets removed.

```r
# Define list and attribute
my_list <- list(1,2,3)
attr(my_list, "my_attribute") <- "foo"

# Function that I will apply over list elements
add_1 <- function (x) {
  return(x + 1)
}

my_list <- lapply(my_list, add_1)

# Attribute is lost
attributes(my_list)
#> NULL
```

How can I keep the list attributes after lapply?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I could just store the attributes before the lapply call

```
# Define list and attribute
...

# Function that I will apply over list elements
...

stored_attributes <- attributes(my_list) 
my_list <- lapply(my_list, add_1) 
attributes(my_list) <- stored_attributes
```

... still, I don't really understand this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

A way to retain the attributes is with `[]` -

```
my_list[] <- lapply(my_list, add_1)

attributes(my_list)
#$my_attribute
#[1] "foo"
```